# Sorting a list using my own function to sort

Tags: sorting, functional-programming, scheme, racket

I'm continue learning Racket and now I need to sort a list using my own function to sort the list.

Each element of the list, which are also lists, needs to passed as parameter to my own function, and the function will return a real value between [0, 1].

In a nutshell: I will have a list of lists that needs to be sorted using a function, that has as parameter a list and it will return a real value between [0, 1].

In Racket, I've found the [sort](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Flist..rkt%29._sort%29%29) function:

```
(sort '(1 3 4 2) <)
```

I need something like that, but instead of using `<`, I need to use my own function.

```
#lang racket

(define my-list '(1 2 3 4) '(5 7 3 1) '(9 4 1 8))

(define my-function
  (lambda (lst)
    (let ([result ; Do my own calculations ])
       result))) ; Result is a real number between [0,1].

(define list-sorted (my-sort my-list my-function))
```

**NOTE**: think about `my-function` like a black-box with a list as an input and a real number as an output.
How can I do it?

I had thought to create another list, `my-list-real-values` with the real number values for each element in `my-list` in the same order, and then using `(sort my-list-real-values <)` to sort it, but I don't know how to link the two lists, `my-list-real-values` with `my-list`, to get sorted `my-list` when I sort `my-list-real-values`.

Maybe I can use [Hash Tables](https://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/hash-tables.html), but I don't know if this is a feature of Racket only, or it can be used with Scheme also.

Comment: `my-list` cannot be 3 values. Perhaps it should be a list of 3 lists? `<` is just the name so you pass anything that can return `#t` if any two of the elements (lists in your case) should be considered lower than the right hand side. If it only took `<`, as in number, you wouldn't bother to ask for a comparison function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work in most Scheme dialects that provide a `sort` procedure:

```
(define (my-sort my-list my-function)
  (sort my-list
        (lambda (l1 l2) (< (my-function l1) (my-function l2)))))
```

As per the [docs](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Flist..rkt%29._sort%29%29), `less-than?` is *any* procedure that:

> Takes two elements of *lst* and returns a true value if the first is less (i.e., should be sorted earlier) than the second

This should also work, but it's Racket-specific:

```
(define (my-sort my-list my-function)
  (sort my-list #:key my-function #:cache-keys? #t <))
```

> The `#:key` argument *extract-key* is used to extract a key value for comparison from each list element.
>
> By default, *extract-key* is applied to two list elements for every comparison, but if *cache-keys?* is true, then the *extract-key* function is used exactly once for each list item. Supply a true value for *cache-keys?* when *extract-key* is an expensive operation

Comment: Thanks. I was working on an implementation using a HashTable and an auxiliary list, with the keys of the hash table, used to sort it and the get the elements in the hash table.

Comment: I'm glad I was able to provide a simpler solution ;)

Comment: Sorry, but my `my-function` has three parameters, the list and another two. How can I pass them inside the sort call? Thanks.

Comment: In that case you need to use the first version of my code, modify it to receive the extra parameters and use them inside the lambda

Comment: I've done this: `(sort lst #:key (lambda (x) (my-function x y z)) #:cache-keys? #t <)`

Comment: No, you can't use the `#:key` solution if you need to pass more than one parameter. Use the first version.